# Javascript getElementById('id').style VS var x

Tags: javascript, css

it seems odd to me that using **document.getElementById('myImg').style.width** instead of **var x = document.getElementById('myImg').style.width** yields different results can anyone explain please?
here's my example code (below, the real code is much longer of course), I'm looking to reduce it as much as I can by storing document.getElementById('myImg').style.width as a variable but upon loading the page it seems to work counter-intuitively...

```
<img id="myImg" src="w3javascript.gif" style="width:100px;height:132px;">

<script>
window.onload = function myFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById('myImg').style.width;
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if(width >= 450){
x = "450px"
}
}
</script>
```

Now the above code produces different results than this (and I have no idea why...):

```
<img id="myImg" src="w3javascript.gif" style="width:100px;height:132px;">

<script>
window.onload = function myFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById('myImg').style.width;
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if(width >= 450){
document.getElementById('myImg').style.width = "450px"
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are trying to modify the DOM in the second case.

Comment: in the first example x contains the value of the width property of a dom element, which is a string, so adjusting it later wont affect the dom. in the second example, you are changing the value of a property of a dom element, so it affects the dom

Answer (score 1):

When you do :

```
var x = document.getElementById('myImg').style.width;
var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if(width >= 450){
  x = "450px"
}
```

you in fact first assign the width of your element to the variable x, **then** you overwrite x with the value "450px", but you don't change the element.

In the second example, `document.getElementById('myImg').style.width = "450px"` actually sets the width of the element, but **doesn't** change the variable x.

To simplify your code, you can use :

```
var x = document.getElementById('myImg');
var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if(width >= 450){
  x.style.width = "450px"
}
```

Comment: So, say I want have different widths for different window sizes - is there no way to do that using a variable? will I have to type the entire document.getElementBy... for each size?

Comment: You can use : `var x = document.getElementById('myImg')` and do : `x.style.width = '450px'`

Comment: it's less ideal (IMO) but thanks! oh and better yet, I can do - var x = document.getElementById('myImg').style and then x.width = '450px'

Comment: @user3086182: if it was the way you thought it was, it would make it more difficult to reason about code. To understand what happens in a specific assignment, you'd first have to trace back where the variable's current value comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a value to a variable **never** changes the value of another variable or property (exceptions: global scope, `with`).

Simpler example:

```
var foo = 42;
var bar = foo;

bar = 21;
// foo is still 42
```

In the first case, you are only changing the value of variable `x`.
In the second case you are changing the value of the property `width`.

JavaScript is [pass-by-value](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_by_value#Call_by_value), not [pass-by-reference](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_by_value#Call_by_reference).

---

If you want to avoid querying for the element twice, either store the element or its style in a variable. For example:

```
var style = document.getElementById('myImg').style;
// ...
style.width = ...;
```

Comment: So, say I want have different widths for different window sizes - is there no way to do that using a variable? will I have to type the entire document.getElementBy... for each size?